# Retrieve all Items inside a Box using JPA

Tags: java, jpa

Each `User` has a `Box`. Each `Box` may contain some `Item`.
My architecture is:

The `Item`:

```
@Entity
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @Column(allowsNull = "false") 
    @Unowned
    private Box location; 
    ...
```

The `Box`:

```
@Entity
public class Box {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="location", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<Item> items;
    ...
```

The `User`:

```
@Entity
public class User{
    @Id
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @Column(allowsNull = "false") 
    @JoinColumn(name="BOX_ID")
    private Box box;
```

If there is any error in this structure, please tell me.

Now I want to retrieve all the `Item` belonging to a `User`, preferably using `javax.persistence.EntityManager`, but I simply cannot.

What I intend to do is something like:

```
Query q1 = em.createQuery("select u from User u where u.username='"+username+"'");
User user = // ... well known code

Query q2 = em.createQuery("select i from Item i where i.location='"+user.box+"'");
Item item = // ... well known code
```

Now I receive this exception:

```
 SELECT u FROM database.entities.Item u WHERE u.location.key='database.entities.Box@3872bb09': Can only reference properties of a sub-object if the sub-object is embedded.
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't use concatenation to pass dynamic parameters to queries. This is inefficient, will fail if the parameter contains a single quote, and opens your code to SQL injection attacks. Use named parameters:

```
select ... where u.username = :name
...
query.setParameter("name", username);
```

Now look at your second query. It searches for items for a location equal to the toString() value of a Box instance. That doesn't make sense. You must pass the box as parameter:

```
Query q2 = em.createQuery("select i from Item i where i.location = :box");
q2.setParameter("box", user.getBox());
```

Note that you don't need two queries for that. A single one is sufficient:

```
select item from User user
inner join user.box box 
inner join box.items item 
where user.username = :name
```